# Videos don't play on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, video

I am building a website: daretogaincontrol.com. On that site, I am using videolightbox to play videos.

The videos don't play on iPad or iPhone. The site works fine on desktops (Mac and PC).

The nice people at videolightbox put together a little test page to show that their player and one of our videos will play on iPad/iPhone here: http://www.videolightbox.com/3/

I copied that code to a test page here: http://www.daretogaincontrol.com/test_video

On the test_video page there are two play options one is playing the video from videolightbox.com with the player from that site. Same as the videolightbox.com page, but served from the daretogaincontrol server. The bottom one attempts to play the same video with the same player but the player and video reside on the daretogaincontrol server.

All the javascript and css on the test_video page are linked to the videolightbox.com site.

Neither video on the test_video page plays on iPad/iPhone, which leads me to believe there might be a server issue, since I can eliminate (?) the video format and player has having identifiable problems.

You can play the video on iPad/iPhone using a direct link: [which you need to figure out on your own because I am limited to 2 links per post, sorry], but not in the player on the page.

I have no iPad/iPhone to test with. I know pretty much nothing about iPad/iPhone. I must make changes and call the client to have them test. I also have little experience with delivering video content over the web.

Comment: I am now thinking it's the iframe tag. On the home page I am using an <a> tag with the href set to the player, on page2 I am using the same value in the <a href= in the <iframe src= because the videos on page2 don't play in a popup overlay. Does anyone know of problems with iframe tags on iPad/iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

By using [these instructions](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html) you can set up your PC to act as a proxy and capture the web traffic.

When I do this, I see the requests are malformed when coming from the iPhone

```
GET http://www.daretogaincontrol.com/test_video
200 OK (text/html)

GET http://www.daretogaincontrol.com/videos/index_videolb/http://www.daretogaincontrol.com/videos/having_fun.mp4
404 Not Found (text/html)

GET http://www.daretogaincontrol.com/videos/index_videolb/http://www.daretogaincontrol.com/videos/having_fun.mp4
404 Not Found (text/html)
```

Comment: Fascinating! I can see the GET is malformed. But where does that get me? And why only on iPad/iPhone? and the BIG question: how to fix?

Comment: Got fiddler running on my PC. Configuration instructions are not exactly clear. It seems there's some setup that has to happen on iPhone/iPad, which I don't have. Also, if iPad is configured with the ip address as shown in the instructions (from the output of my ipconfig command): 192.168.1.2 (the ip provided to my PC by my router), I can't see how the iPad of my client will resolve that. So, I'm more than a little confused as to how to proceed. Any further details will be most appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't know much about it, you may have to ask them. One thing I see different from your example and theirs is that the `url=` param in the href is fully qualified in yours and not in theirs. It may or may not be related to that.

Comment: The PC and the iPad have to be on the same network, so your pc might be 192.168.1.2 and your ipad might be 192.168.1.20. Your pc's firewall might need to be turned off.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.... can't test it here. If you have any insight as to what to try to make a fix I would appreciate it. I have alerted videolightbox vendor to your discovery.

Comment: I have been unable to confirm the site is playing videos on page2 on iPad and iPhone. I removed all path from video filenames, I put the player.swf in the same directory as the videos and I made the href="videos/player.swf" - so it's relative to the document root. Don't know what else to do. Would gladly accept your answer if you actually provide one.