# videos don't play in iframe on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, iframe

I am using videolightbox to play videos on my site. It works (on all platforms) on the homepage where the video pops up in an overlay. To do that I use:

```
    <a href="videos/player.swf?url=videos/filename.mp4">
```

on page2 (see: http://daretogaincontrol.com/page2?title=Having%20Fun)

I use an iframe tag like so:

```
    <iframe src="videos/player.swf?url=videos/filename.mp4">
```

And that doesn't work. I'm not sure it's the iframe, but I've been around several circles trying to figure out why the videos don't play on iPad and iPhone (see [Videos don't play on iPad/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871740/videos-dont-play-on-ipad-iphone)).

Works on all other platforms. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that your code is using an '.swf' file to play the .mp4 video.

Apple products do not facilitate the use of flash (.swf) objects.

You can bypass this by using something like the following code;

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="340" height="280" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
<param name="SRC" value="video.mp4"> 
<param name="AUTOPLAY" value="false">
<param name="CONTROLLER" value="false">
<embed src="video.mp4" width="340" height="260" autoplay="false" controller="false" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">+
</object>
```

Hope this helps mate.